# Seating chart starts to output wrong permutations in Prolog

Tags: algorithm, prolog, permutation

I have a homework assignment where I must write a predicate `seatingChart(X):-` which will have 8 seats. The rules are:

1. Adjacent seating partners must be of the opposite gender.
2. Adjacent seating partners must share at least one of the same hobby.

I thought I wrote the code below to create the correct case.

> ```
> person(jim,m).
> person(tom,m).
> person(joe,m).
> person(bob,m).
> person(fay,f).
> person(beth,f).
> person(sue,f).
> person(cami,f).
>
> % Database of hobbies
> % hobbies(name,hobby). -> People can have multiple hobbies)
> hobbies(jim, sup).
> hobbies(jim, fish).
> hobbies(jim, kayak).
> hobbies(tom, hike).
> hobbies(tom, fish).
> hobbies(tom, ski).
> hobbies(joe, gamer).
> hobbies(joe, chess).
> hobbies(joe, climb).
> hobbies(bob, paint).
> hobbies(bob, yoga).
> hobbies(bob, run).
> hobbies(fay, sup).
> hobbies(fay, dance).
> hobbies(fay, run).
> hobbies(beth, climb).
> hobbies(beth, cycle).
> hobbies(beth, fish).
> hobbies(sue, yoga).
> hobbies(sue, skate).
> hobbies(sue, ski).
> hobbies(cami, run).
> hobbies(cami, kayak).
> hobbies(cami, gamer).
>
> %% ANSWER %%
>
> % return a pair of opposite gender people
> gender(PersonX, PersonY):-
>   person(PersonX,GenderX),
>   person(PersonY,GenderY),
>   GenderX \= GenderY.
>
> % return the pair of similar interests.
> similarHobbies(PersonX, PersonY):-
>   hobbies(PersonX, HobbyX),
>   hobbies(PersonY, HobbyY),
>   HobbyX == HobbyY.
>
> % Create the rules for our seating chart list
> seatingRules([P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8|_]):-
>   % Have each adjacent person be of the opposite gender
>   gender(P1,P2),
>   gender(P3,P4),
>   gender(P5,P6),
>   gender(P7,P8),
>   gender(P8,P1),
>   % Have each adjacent person have at least one of the same hobby
>   similarHobbies(P1,P2),
>   similarHobbies(P3,P4),
>   similarHobbies(P5,P6),
>   similarHobbies(P7,P8).
>
> % Generate a list of all the names from person(...)
> people(P):-
>   findall(X, person(X,_), P).
>
> % Generate a list of permutations of people
> permPeople([P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8]):-
>   permutation([P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8],
>                   [jim,tom,joe,bob,fay,beth,sue,cami]),
>   \+error([P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8]).
>
> error([P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8]):-
>   \+seatingRules([P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8]).
>
> seatingChart(X):-
>   permPeople(X).
> ```

When I run this using `seatingChart(X).` in SWI-Prolog I get the following answer first:

`X = [jim, fay, tom, beth, joe, cami, bob, sue] ;`

However, my subsequent permutations seem to be flat out wrong.. after hitting `;` a few more times this says it's a valid answer:

`X = [jim, beth, sue, tom, joe, cami, bob, fay] .`

What am I doing wrong? Or what is causing my permutations to start not following the seating chart rules?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the seating rule predicate contain all pairs?

```
% Create the rules for our seating chart list
seatingRules([P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8|_]):-
  % Have each adjacent person be of the opposite gender
  gender(P1,P2),
  gender(P2,P3),
  gender(P3,P4),
  gender(P4,P5),
  gender(P5,P6),
  gender(P6,P7),
  gender(P7,P8),
  gender(P8,P1),
  % Have each adjacent person have at least one of the same hobby
  similarHobbies(P1,P2),
  similarHobbies(P2,P3),
  similarHobbies(P3,P4),
  similarHobbies(P4,P5),
  similarHobbies(P5,P6),
  similarHobbies(P6,P7),
  similarHobbies(P7,P8),
  similarHobbies(P8,P1).
```

Comment: True, I just updated it, but I still end up with the same results later on. Basically, the same genders end up sitting next to each other..